# Finding the Corresponding Max Value in a Data Frame

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following code

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'sport' : ['football', 'hockey', 'baseball', 'basketball', 'nan'], 'league': ['NFL', 'NHL', 'MLB', 'NBA', 'NaN'], 'number': [1,2,3,4,'']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df
```

I'd like to print out the `sport` with the highest `number`

I've tried the following code:

```
highestnumberedsport = df[df['number'] == df['number'].max()]
```

However, this gives me the entire row.  I'd like to only print out the value in the `sport` column.

[image]

Update:  I've tried the following based on suggestion, but this still does not output the desired string of 'basketball' in this instance:

[image]

```
df.loc[df['number'] == df['number'].max(), 'sport']
```

how do I only print out the sport that has the highest value?

Comment: `df.loc[df['number'] == df['number'].max(), 'sport']`

Comment: @Quang Hoang this also outputs the following: ```3    basketball
Name: sport, dtype: object```; how do I get it to just output the string 'basketball' for this particular example?

Comment: `df.loc[df['number'].idxmax(), 'sport']`.